# How to subtract the sum of value using left join?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `orders` and `customers`:

```
select * from orders;
+------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| oid  | date                | customer_id | amount |
+------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
|  102 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           4 |    300 |
|  100 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |  15000 |
|  101 | 2008-10-08 00:00:00 |           2 |   1300 |
|  105 | 2010-10-08 00:00:00 |           1 |    400 |
|  106 | 2014-12-23 00:00:00 |           3 |    300 |
+------+---------------------+-------------+--------+

select * from customers;
+------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| id   | name   | age  | address   | salary   |
+------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
|    1 | ramesh |   32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|    2 | khilan |   25 | delhi     |  1500.00 |
|    3 | muffy  |   22 | bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|    4 | suresh |   48 | mumbai    | 24000.00 |
|    1 | ramesh |   32 | Ahmedabad |   300.00 |
|    5 | akil   |   21 | madurai   |  1000.00 |
|    6 | rajesh |   22 | delhi     |  5000.00 |
+------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
```

What I'm trying to do is to do `SUM(salary)` from `customers` and subtract it with the `SUM(amount)` from `orders` table. I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT id ,NAME,SUM(salary),SUM(amount),SUM(salary)-SUM(amount) 
FROM customers a LEFT JOIN orders b ON a.id=b.customer_id  
GROUP BY NAME;
```

This will return the following result, which some of them return incorrect value:

```
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| id   | name   | SUM(salary) | SUM(amount) | SUM(salary)-SUM(amount) |
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|    5 | akil   |     1000.00 |        NULL |                    NULL |
|    2 | khilan |     1500.00 |        1300 |                  200.00 |
|    3 | muffy  |    17000.00 |       15300 |                 1700.00 |
|    6 | rajesh |     5000.00 |        NULL |                    NULL |
|    1 | ramesh |     2300.00 |         800 |                 1500.00 |
|    4 | suresh |    24000.00 |         300 |                23700.00 |
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

My expected output is as following:

```
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| id   | name   | SUM(salary) | SUM(amount) | SUM(salary)-SUM(amount) |
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|    5 | akil   |     1000.00 |        NULL |                    1000 |
|    2 | khilan |     1500.00 |        1300 |                  200.00 |
|    3 | muffy  |    8500     |       15300 |                 -6800   |
|    6 | rajesh |     5000.00 |        NULL |                    5000 |
|    1 | ramesh |     2300.00 |         400 |                 1900.00 |
|    4 | suresh |    24000.00 |         300 |                23700.00 |
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Should customers with the same id have multiple salaries in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

1. One way is to make calculation on `orders` into sub-query.
2. To cater for `NULL` value, you can use `IFNULL(value,0)`.

```
    SELECT id,NAME,SUM(salary),amt,SUM(salary)-IFNULL(amt,0)
        FROM customers a LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) amt FROM orders GROUP BY customer_id) b 
        ON a.id=b.customer_id  
    GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: your first query with DISTINCT can cause wrong results when there are same amount orders for same customer.

Comment: You're right @ChinthakaFernando .. let me remove that suggestion. thanks